# How do I get the difference in minutes from 2 timestamp columns?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Can't seem to figure this out. Just need the difference in minutes between 2 oracle timestamp columns.

```
END_TS                                  START_TS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-NOV-13 01.52.14.000000 PM                            11-NOV-13 01.51.14.000000 PM
11-NOV-13 02.20.47.000000 PM                            11-NOV-13 02.19.47.000000 PM
18-NOV-13 12.44.54.000000 PM                            18-NOV-13 12.34.02.000000 PM
22-NOV-13 12.02.09.000000 AM                            22-NOV-13 12.02.08.000000 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND( (END_TS - START_TS) * 24 * 60, 0) DifferenceInMinutes 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I get results in the form of:

    DIFFERENCEINMINUTES
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    +000000000 00:00:00.000000000
    +000000000 00:00:00.000000000
    +000000010 20:48:00.000000000
    +000000000 00:24:00.000000000
    +000000000 00:00:00.000000000

Comment: Added ROUND() to round off the minutes to 0 after decimal. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ( CAST(END_TS AS DATE) - CAST(START_TS AS DATE)) * 24 * 60 from dual
```

and round it if required